# Hide site content after login

Tags: php, authentication, hide, dreamweaver

Im creating a site using Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 and I have added a `login` function there. I have also added a Dynamic Text session `MM_Username` that displays the logged in users name in the page.  However, my problem here is that every time someone is not logged in, dynamic text shows an ugly `error` message. I'd like to hide this content from my page every time someone logs in. Is there some simple solution to do it like wrapping the text with some php code?  Any help would be appreciated since I've pretty much looked everywhere.  Thanks in advance.

-John

Answer (score 0):

From memory (been a few years now) I believe in the server behavior panel, there is an option to "show region if" or something similar.

Failing that you can wrap the offending content in an if similar to this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) { ?> your content here <?php } ?>
```

Or this which I personally find more readable when mixing html and php:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) : ?> your content here <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check firstly when user logged_in, If he/she is logged in then,

```
if(isset(session['var'])){ ?>
 < your html content here using CSS hide property >
<?php } else { ?> 
 < Your html content goes here using CSS show property>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does exact of what you want for me; hope it helps

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] == 'teacher') { ?>
<div class="home"><a href="dashboard.php"><img src="images/ico-folder.png" width="32" height="31" /></a></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```